# Смешение прямой и косвенной речи

Tags: прямая-речь

По мнению Кипеня, эти люди стоят за такими радикальными решениями, как национализация и мобилизация населения в ополчение: "Это одна из наиболее радикальных группировок, всерьез вознамерившихся расколоть Украину".

Возможно ли такое оформление  прямой речи?

Не будет ли правильным писать так:

По мнению Кипеня, эти люди стоят за такими радикальными решениями, как национализация и мобилизация населения в ополчение.

"Это одна из наиболее радикальных группировок, всерьез вознамерившихся расколоть Украину", - говорит он.

Или первый вариант тоже возможен?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант (1) неверен, так как первое предложение не является словами автора.

Второй вариант возможен, но очень растянут.

Лучше оформить предложение следующим образом: 
По мнению Кипеня, эти люди стоят за такими радикальными решениями, как национализация и мобилизация населения в ополчение, и именно они  составляют одну из наиболее радикальных группировок, всерьез вознамерившихся расколоть Украину.

Answer (score 2):

Вы совершенно правы. Первый вариант неудачный.В первом варианте , если цитата приведена без изменений, то правильно будет такое оформление: По мнению Кипеня, "эти люди стоят за такими радикальными решениями, как национализация и мобилизация населения в ополчение. Это одна из наиболее радикальных группировок, всерьез вознамерившихся расколоть Украину". 
Если же цитата первая  приведена с изменениями, то конечно, правильным будет ваш вариант.

**Правило**

Цитаты могут включаться в текст с помощью вводных слов и предложений. В этих случаях они выделяются кавычками и начинаются со строчной буквы. Например: Как отмечает В.Г.Белинский, << русский язык  один из богатейших языков в мире…>>; Молодым людям надо как можно больше читать хороших книг, так как, по словам А.С.Пушкина, <<следовать за мыслями великого человека - наука самая занимательная>>.

А так, с точки зрения стилистики, конечно, София права.

Если вдуматься, то естественно, после "по мнению" логичен пересказ. Однако я нашел такое предложение: Госсекретарь США сказал, что, *по его мнению,* "за организацией этих нападений стоит Россия"...  В той же статье, откуда doom приводит цитату еще встречается подобные предложения. Вот я и подумал, может, журналисты неправильно написали.

Совершенно верно! Интересно, кто пишет такие статьи?!

Comment: Серж, а в думаете, что после вводных слов "по мнению кого-то" может следовать дословная цитата? Я посмотрела в Нацкорпусе, там обычно идет пересказ содержания без кавычек. Может быть, цитаты следуют только после "по словам", "как отмечает"?

Comment: Здесь "по его мнению", скорее, нужно включить в цитату: Госсекретарь США сказал, что "по его мнению, за организацией этих нападений стоит Россия". А то непонятно: это Госсекретарь высказывает мнение или утверждает факт? И еще один момент. В Вашем варианте цитирования два предложения, причем первое начинается со строчной буквы. Даже если мы используем формулу "по словам", то два предложения в такую конструкцию как-то не вписываются.

Comment: "По его мнению" нельзя включать в цитату. Человек о себе не говорит "по его мнению", а только "по моему мнению", но первое лицо в косвенной речи невозможно. Было как раз правильно: Госсекретарь США сказал, что, по его мнению, за организацией этих нападений стоит Россия. Или: Госсекретарь США сказал: "По моему мнению, за организацией этих нападений стоит Россия".

Comment: Во-первых, надо различать  два разных смысла. (1)Госсекретарь США сказал: "По моему мнению, за организацией этих нападений стоит Россия".  (2)Госсекретарь США сказал: "За организацией этих нападений стоит Россия". С точки зрения дипломатии, разница весьма существенная. Во-вторых, в косвенной речи делается замена местоимений: Он сказал: "Я думаю..". Он сказал, что он думает..." Он сказал: "По моему мнению...". Он сказал, что "по его мнению..."

Comment: Он сказал, что "по его мнению..." - такая конструкция недопустима, если это мнение говорящего. Она прочитывается как мнение третьего лица: Он сказал, что "по мнению Васи..."

Comment: Не допускается кем-то неизвестным , потому что кем-то другим субъективно и неправильно может быть прочитано. С точки зрения логичности интересная постановка вопроса. Впрочем, опыт жизни показывает, что логические уставки  некоторых людей принципиально несовместимы, и обсуждение теории в этом случае пустая трата времени. Лучше сформулировать практическую задачу: пожалуйста, приведите варианты косвенной речи для представленных выше вариантов (1) и (2) прямой речи.

Comment: София, тут даже не надо искать ссылки на правила. ЦИТАТА потому и цитата, что неприкосновенна. Если человек сказал "по моему мнению", то в кавычках никак не может оказаться "по его мнению". Все элементы косвенной речи выносятся за пределы цитаты. (1) Госсекретарь США сказал, что, по его мнению, "за организацией этих нападений стоит Россия". (2)Госсекретарь США сказал, что "за организацией этих нападений стоит Россия".